# Phantom JS Karma runner connects but doesn't execute tests in C9.io

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, cloud9-ide

I followed the directions as per the Karma website to run Karma in the Cloud9 IDE (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/plus/cloud9.html)

my karma.config correctly contains:

```
    hostname: process.env.IP,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    runnerPort: 0,
```

my terminal output:

```
Running "karma:test" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again.
```

I am able to see the words "Karma starting..." at
 http://..c9.io/

However, I receive the following error logged in my console:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test-raptoria.c9.io/?  
 _c9_id=livepreview24&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io' was loaded 
 over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest 
 endpoint http://test-raptoria.c9.io/socket.io/
 EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426358810471-0'. This
 request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?? It seems like the requests are being blocked..

I've shared my workspace here:
https://ide.c9.io/raptoria/test

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change the request to socket.io to https? If that is not possible, Try loading the test-raptoria.c9.io with http instead of https.

Comment: tried both adding a proxy to my config, which didn't seem to do anything, and the second thing you recommended which resulted in this                       error GET http://test-raptoria.c9.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426365936179-0 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded my entire workspace from test (without the data folder and dependencies), and created a new one called simple. I ran 'grunt test' again and it works. I must've corrupted my old workspace somehow.

Problem solved!
Thanks for helping me look into this.